# An error started the container after enabling @EnableOauth2Sso.Error creating bean with name 'jwtTokenServices' defined in class path resource

Tags: java, oauth-2.0

#### In the service enabling @EnableOauth2Sso, enable configuration security.oauth2.resource.jwt.key-uri  report an error,and there will be no error in the service that enables @EnableResourceServer

[tim 20190201102130](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/27875141/52098837-a1a5bc80-260b-11e9-8a07-f8264e6cb469.png)

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jwtTokenServices' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/resource/ResourceServerTokenServicesConfiguration$JwtTokenServicesConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'jwtTokenServices' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jwtTokenStore' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/resource/ResourceServerTokenServicesConfiguration$JwtTokenServicesConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenStore]: Factory method 'jwtTokenStore' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jwtTokenEnhancer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/resource/ResourceServerTokenServicesConfiguration$JwtTokenServicesConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JwtAccessTokenConverter]: Factory method 'jwtTokenEnhancer' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/jwt/crypto/sign/MacSigner
>
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jwtTokenStore' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/resource/ResourceServerTokenServicesConfiguration$JwtTokenServicesConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenStore]: Factory method 'jwtTokenStore' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jwtTokenEnhancer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/resource/ResourceServerTokenServicesConfiguration$JwtTokenServicesConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JwtAccessTokenConverter]: Factory method 'jwtTokenEnhancer' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/jwt/crypto/sign/MacSigner

Comment: Please add description for the error or problem

Comment: I am getting the same error right now... did u get any solution for this?
I have three stages and i see this issue only in dev but not on test and prod.

Comment: @sdake did you get the solution for this??